# Illegal start of expressions in Java file

Tags: java, process, expression, program-entry-point

This is the code where I get error.  How to call a parameterized method?

I am very new in coding.

```java
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Main arr= new Main ();
       arr.process();
    }
        public void process(String input)
        {
            String[] vals= input.split(" ");
            int[] score=new int[vals.length];
            int total=0;
            for(int i=0; i<score.length; i++)
            {
                score[i]=Integer.parseInt(vals[i]);
                total+=score[i];                  
            }
            double Average(double)total/score.length;
            System.out.println(Average);            
        }
    }
```

Error:

> ```
>   The method process() in the type Main
> ```
>
> .    Is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Hey! Show the whole error message, please.

Comment: Can above java code will run??

Comment: You have put the method ```process``` into the function ```main``` which is illegal in Java. Put the method ```process``` in scope of the class ```Main```.

Comment: Still not running.

Comment: How to correct it. Without main method it is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Main arr= new Main ();
       arr.process("76,65,87,98,100");
    }
        public void process(String input)
        {
            String[] vals= input.split(" ");
            int[] score=new int[vals.length];
            int total=0;
            for(int i=0; i<score.length; i++)
            {
                score[i]=Integer.parseInt(vals[i]);
                total+=score[i];                  
            }
            double Average(double)total/score.length;
            System.out.println(Average);            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Process method should be outside Main method. Also process method should be static because instance of Main class is not needed in order to execute process method. Scanner class is called ( import java.util.Scanner). The java.util.Scanner class is a simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.  In process method scanner sc reads string input until it comes to an end of a string. To find more about scanner https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String inputString = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8";
            process(inputString);
        }
        public static void process(String input)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int length = 0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
            while( sc.hasNextInt() ) {
                total += sc.nextInt();
                ++length;
            }
            double Average =  (double)total / length;

            System.out.println( Average );            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am learning arrays. Your answer is not using any array.